# Save deb out of synaptic

Tags: deb, ubuntu-gnome, synaptic, gdebi

I've downloaded the game Assault cube 1.2 and didn't save a copy from

> /var/cache/apt/archives/

Is there a way to copy or save an installed software out of Synaptic and save it as deb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read `man apt-get`.

```
sudo apt-get --download-only --reinstall install assaultcube assaultcube-data
```

will leave the `.deb`s in `/var/cache/apt/archives`

Comment: So this command will redownload the package? @waltinator?

Comment: I was hoping for a way that didn't involve downloading packages, but thanks anyway!

Comment: Danger Will Robinson! Do not ever do `sudo anything` before you read `man anything` and understand what the command will do.